# How to always set correct number of tag before every run htmlUnit or Selenium test? Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, htmlunit

I would like to ask you, if is possible to renumber (automatically) my tags in testing script before every start (Test defined in include) ... no shortcuts. My goal is always actual and right number of step in log.

Comment: Not really following you. Can you add more info?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a counter function. give a parameter at start to reset and whenever you called it, counter increment by 1